# Creating events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

If I have a list of functions that are serving as event subscriptions, is there an advantage to running through them and calling them with `.call()` (B below), or more directly (A)?  The code is below.  The only difference I can see is that with `.call` you can control what `this` is set to.  Is there any other difference besides that?

```
    $(function() {
        eventRaiser.subscribe(function() { alert("Hello"); });
        eventRaiser.subscribe(function(dt) { alert(dt.toString()); });

        eventRaiser.DoIt();
    });

    var eventRaiser = new (function() {
        var events = [];
        this.subscribe = function(func) {
            events.push(func);
        };

        this.DoIt = function() {
            var now = new Date();
            alert("Doing Something Useful");
            for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                events[i](now);  //A
                events[i].call(this, now);  //B
            }
        };
    })();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no other difference. If you follow the second approach though, you can extend `subscribe` so that the "clients" can specify the context to be used:

```
this.subscribe = function(func, context) {
     events.push({func: func, context: context || this});
};

this.DoIt = function() {
    var now = new Date();
    alert("Doing Something Useful");
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        events[i].func.call(events[i].context, now);
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to go with method B, you can allow the function that subscribes to the event, to perform event specific functions.

For instance, you could use `this.getDate()` inside your function (you would have to create the method) instead of passing the date as a parameter. Another helpful method inside an Event class would be `this.getTarget()`.